# tinymce displays raw html code and no Buttons for one user in IE7 , 4 others users have not problems. If that user uses Foxfire it works perfectly

Tags: tinymce

I have 5 users (3 locations) using the pages that have Tiny_MCE text areas.

I receive No Errors and it works Perfectly on the other 4 machines running IE7 This would  indicate there is No JavaScript Errors.

One user only is seeing the raw html code and no buttons at all.

I suspect it must be some IE setting that is wrong. 
It does not appear that Javascript is disabled, as other Javascript functions work on that same site on the same machine in IE. 
This user is running XP Pro, and IE 7.

*When I installed FireFox on his machine, the Tiny_MCE works perfectly. This would Also indicate there is No JavaScript Errors.*

I'm at a loss to explain it. 
Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is foxfire the same is firefox?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I only use it or Crome to test my compliance to coding rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny thing. The problem fixed itself with no human assistance. No Reboot, No Nothing. after being AFU for 2 weeks, it just started working again.

**Got to Love Windows!**

Answer (score 0):

Once I ran into same issue and the fix was to remove a comma at the end of the script. So check whether the error pattern is present in your code.

For example, the following code contains a bug which will prevent it from running in IE7.

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode: "textareas",
    theme: "advanced",
    ...
    template_replace_values: {
        username: "Some User",
        staffid: "991234"
    }, // <<< BUG - Additional comma here
});
```

If you can enable javascript debugging in IE7 then post the js error here.

Comment: The extra comma was not present and this script runs on other machines running IE7. It is a setting local to the one user's machine

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this before and it has always been a caching issue. Use Ctrl-F5 in IE to force a full refresh of the page and all its files (*.css, *.js) in the browser and the browser cache. My guess is the IE 7 computer that was bad had a 14 day setting for checking if files were up to date.

Sometimes it's been worse - the web server (tomcat 5.5) would cache the file too and not notice the file was updated. Restarting the web server fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same problem with our software last few months.

I found this forum topic on developer's website:
http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?pid=66594

In short words, he is recommending to set strict_loading_mode to true when initializing tinymce. I've done that, and since that i had no problems.